# Why sometimes does my lower menu (ADWLauncher - Dockbar) disappears?

Tags: browser, launcher, settings, adw.launcher, menu

I have the following Android Desktop, using Cyanogenmod:

[image]

Sometimes, I don't remember how or why, it becomes like this:

[image]

As you can see, the lower menu (dockbar) just disappears, and only Browser's icon is shown. I have to restart my phone so I can get my menu back. I'm using ADWLauncher.

What am I doing to lose my lower menu? Where am I clicking? I have no idea how to return to the previous state unless I restart my phone... :/

Comment: Have you tried any hot reboot app to fix...

Comment: I think there might be a particular swipe gesture that hides the dockbar, but I'm not sure what it is offhand. You may be able to find it in ADW's settings, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem before.
user:eldarerathis was correct. It is swipe gesture that suppose to hide menu when you don't need it, but AFAIK, there's no way to turn it off. 
So, to get it back you should do gesture starting roughly a bit above Browser icon and swipe down(or up).

I've fixed that another way - simply installed different launcher. Problem didn't appear

Comment: Actually, it's possible to disable it. Settings -> ADWLauncher -> General Behavior -> Swipe down actions | Swipe up action -> NONE. Thanks for at least giving me names of what exactly is that menu (ADW launcher).

Answer (score 3):

Had this as well with the ADW Launcher from CyanogenMod.

What you need to do is **sweep downward in the place where the bar disappeared**. You also hide it that way, probably accidentally like I did many times :D

I had been thinking why this feature was there but can't think of anything, just to annoy users is my best guess.